# Positive/Negative interference in a carrier signal

Tags: homework

So my problem is that a 800MHz carrier signal arrives at a receiver via two paths that differ in length by a distance of ∆d. I am unsure how I would determine the smallest values for when negative and positive interference occur, along with phase difference at 100m. The only value given is the MHz so I dont know how I would calculate any of these things other than getting the wavelength. I am basically stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For exact cancellation, you need 180 degrees or 1/2 wavelength. 900 MHz has 1/3 meter wavelength, thus 1/6 meter delay is needed. For 800 MHz,
you need 1/6 * 900/800 = 9/48 meters.

This assumes the delayed path provides exactly the same energy (no attenuation) as the direct path.

Comment: @ Bruan Drummond. Yes. Thank you. Late night proofreading is iffy.